# $1989$ Russian Mathematical Olympiad

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Find the positive integers $n$ with exactly $12$ divisors
$1 = d_1 < d_2 < · · · < d_{12} = n$ such that the divisor with index d4 (that is, $d_{d_4 − 1}$) is $(d_1 + d_2 + d_4)d_8$

It said that there exists an $1<i<12$ such that $d_i = d_1+d_2+d_4$, but the book did not explain why, it does not seem trivial for me

Comment: divisor with index $d_4$ (that is, $d_{d_4}-1$)? Why $-1$?

Comment: Im also not sure, but the problem used $d_d_4-1$ so i guess dont mind that sentence

Comment: I saw a similar problem and this part was $d_{d_2-1}$

Comment: ah mybad it was actually $d_{d_4-1}$ edited

Comment: If one divisor is $(d_1+d_2+d_4)d_8$, then $d_1+d_2+d_4$ is also a divisor. What is confusing you? This is not a general fact, e.g. it doesn't work for 150, but only for those numbers that have a divisor of the form $(d_1+d_2+d_4)d_8$.

Comment: This question was asked before here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626256/a-number-n-has-12-divisors-and-d-d-4-1-d-1d-2d-4d-8/1699860#1699860 .

Comment: @iam_agf also, https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Mlt2O1rR9xIC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22Find+the+positive+integers+n+with+exactly+12+divisors%22&source=bl&ots=OYpYEh32lH&sig=6HIdHDqTaRWkExebLvi5jOKAwNg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Oy57U63pLY7fkgWAm4GQDw#v=onepage&q=%22Find%20the%20positive%20integers%20n%20with%20exactly%2012%20divisors%22&f=false

Comment: Hint : $n = d_1 . d_{12} = d_2 . d_{11} =...= d_5 . d_8 =...$